# How to eliminate extra uid from appearing in firebase push

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have the following push query for my firebase database.

```
setVisitorAttendanceDate = (orgId, attendeeUid, date) => this.db.ref(`organization/${orgId}/visitor-attendance/${date}`).push({[attendeeUid]: true});
```

This creates the following:

```
- visitor-attendance
- 2020-11-30-PM
-MNSIxmbzLwlW5Dq83Ws
-MNSIxm_woAnBAkVQWRV: true
```

It adds the date as expected but it adds an extra UID.

Right after the date it adds this uid for the object:

```
-MNSIxmbzLwlW5Dq83Ws
```

How can I make it to be with out that UID?  So this

```
- visitor-attendance
- 2020-11-30-PM
-MNSIxm_woAnBAkVQWRV: true
```

Comment: A single push will only ever add a single child to the database.  Something else is going on here that we can't see.  I suggest adding some logging every time you write the database to find out what causes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, everything in the Realtime Database are key: value pairs. When a path is defined and you .push in that path, a node with a child key: value pair is created that sits 'under' that path.

If you look at the code, you're actually defining a path to the data with the final last component being `date`

```
this.db.ref(`organization/${orgId}/visitor-attendance/${date}`).push({[attendeeUid]: true});
                                                         ^^^ path          ^^^ key   ^^^ value
```

with the path being

```
organization
   orgId
      visitor-attendance
         date
           the pushID
               MNSIxm_woAnBAkVQWRV: true
```

From the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists)

> The push() method generates a unique key every time a new child is
> added to the specified Firebase reference.

One possible fix is to use .set as shown in the [Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

> For basic write operations, you can use set() to save data to a
> specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

Comment: I ended up changing push to update and it worked.  Thank you for the answer I upvoted it.

Comment: @FabricioG Excellent! Glad it helped. If it lead to a solution, accepting it is the best practice so it can help others as well. See [How To Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The above comment and answer were very helpful.  I ended up solving this by changing `push` to `update`.

The code now reads:

```
setVisitorAttendanceDate = (orgId, attendeeUid, date) => this.db.ref(`organization/${orgId}/visitor-attendance/${date}`).update({[attendeeUid]: true});
```